# Create class instance using Delphi inline assembler

Tags: delphi, inline-assembly, basm

What I would like to do is, using assembly, create a class instance, call one of it's methods and then free the instance.

I know I'm missing something very important and probably very simple, but I don't know what.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TSomeClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FCreateDateTime: string;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure SayYeah;
  end;

constructor TSomeClass.Create;
begin
  FCreateDateTime := DateTimeToStr(Now);
end;

procedure TSomeClass.SayYeah;
begin
  Writeln('yeah @ ' + FCreateDateTime);
end;

procedure Doit;
asm
  CALL TSomeClass.Create; // <= Access Violation
  CALL TSomeClass.SayYeah;
  CALL TSomeClass.Free;
end;

begin
  try
    Doit;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

FYI: I want to understand how I can achieve this at low level, not another way of doing it.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to Andreas Rejbrand, I've managed to find the culprit:

**Update2**:

Thanks to Arnaud for finding flaw using EBX, rather than PUSH/POP EAX

```
var
  TSomeClass_TypeInfo: Pointer;

procedure Doit;
asm
  MOV DL, $01;
  MOV EAX, TSomeClass_TypeInfo;
  CALL TSomeClass.Create;
  PUSH EAX;
  CALL TSomeClass.SayYeah; // call method
  POP EAX;
  MOV DL, $01;
  CALL TSomeClass.Free; // pointer to instance(Self) is expected in EAX
end;

begin
  TSomeClass_TypeInfo := TSomeClass;
  try
    Doit;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: EBX needs to be saved - have a look at Arnaud's answer

Comment: @PhiS yes Sir, I've read Arnaud's answer, whomever is interested in this, will read all answers(only 2) and comments (:

Comment: the thing is that in your update to the question you are using EBX without saving it. Please fix this (e.g. push ebx/pop ebx), since if you don't you run the risk that a real program using such a function might just crash -- and the reason for this would be very hard to find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about this in an excellent guide to Delphi assembly programming, originally found [here](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3766.asp). Unfortunately, the site is down, but you can find an archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080512034634/http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3766.asp). Look in particular at [page 5](http://web.archive.org/web/20080512043601/http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3770.asp).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: @Kev: I am perfectly aware of that, and that's the reason why I only sent this answer after being requested to do so. Originally, I only gave the link as a comment, although that is not apparent any longer (since you deleted the comments). Unfortunately, I don't have time/energy right now to learn the topics on the page I linked to.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - I rolled old revision back, since it is better than nothing and can help others.

Answer (score 11):

Your asm code is not correct.

You are overloading the `ebx` register, which must be preserved. And the global variable trick does not make sense.

A better coding should be:

```
procedure Doit(ClassType: pointer);
asm // eax=TList
  mov dl,true // hidden boolean 2nd parameter
  call TObject.Create
  push eax
  call TList.Pack
  pop eax
  call TObject.Free
end;

DoIt(TList);
```

But it does not protect the instance with a `try...finally`. :)

About the `mov dl,true` parameter, see [this official page from the EMB wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control):

> Constructors and destructors use the same calling conventions as other
>   methods, except that an additional Boolean flag parameter is passed to
>   indicate the context of the constructor or destructor call.
>
> A value of
>   False in the flag parameter of a constructor call indicates that the
>   constructor was invoked through an instance object or using the
>   inherited keyword. In this case, the constructor behaves like an
>   ordinary method. A value of True in the flag parameter of a
>   constructor call indicates that the constructor was invoked through a
>   class reference. In this case, the constructor creates an instance of
>   the class given by Self, and returns a reference to the newly created
>   object in EAX.
>
> A value of False in the flag parameter of a destructor call indicates
>   that the destructor was invoked using the inherited keyword. In this
>   case, the destructor behaves like an ordinary method. A value of True
>   in the flag parameter of a destructor call indicates that the
>   destructor was invoked through an instance object. In this case, the
>   destructor deallocates the instance given by Self just before
>   returning.
>
> The flag parameter behaves as if it were declared before all other
>   parameters. Under the register convention, it is passed in the DL
>   register. Under the pascal convention, it is pushed before all other
>   parameters. Under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions, it is
>   pushed just before the Self parameter.
>
> Since the DL register indicates whether the constructor or destructor
>   is the outermost in the call stack, you must restore the value of DL
>   before exiting so that BeforeDestruction or AfterConstruction can be
>   called properly.

So an alternate valid coding, since `eax` our object is not `nil` so we can call the *destructor* directly, could be:

```
procedure Doit(ClassType: pointer);
asm // eax=TList
  mov dl,true
  call TObject.Create
  push eax
  call TList.Pack
  pop eax
  mov dl,true
  call TList.Destroy
end;
```

In all case, object access from `asm` is not meant to be done this way. You do not have access to the type information directly, so it may be very difficult to work with it. With an existing `class` instance, you can do whatever you want with `asm` methods; but to create instances, and play with class types, `asm` is definitively not the natural way!

Comment: +1 thank you for the catch, side note: I wanted to contact you privately(regarding some of your projects), can you give me a link to where I can get your e-mail or give it directly please?

Comment: @DorinDuminica If it is about the synopse projects, the main entry point is the forum at http://synopse.info but you can also write directly to me webcontact01 at synopse dot info :)

Comment: Why is necessary to push and pop the eax there ?

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino Because eax=self so is needed for property TList.Destroy call.